# Extract a specific term 'hardrock'

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a specific word 'hardrock' using regex from the following sentence

**Given sentence:**

```
hardrock,victor,alpha,matt,hardrock-victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock
```

I just need the word hardrock and not the word hardrock-victor from the sentence.

**Given sentence:**

> **hardrock**,victor,alpha,matt,hardrock-victor,ben,**hardrock**,rocker,ranzian,**hardrock**

I tried using the regex `(hardrock,|,hardrock,|,hardrock)` but it matches with the hardrock-victor as well. https://www.regextester.com/15

Please help me with a regex which only extracts all the hardrock and not the hardrock-victor

Comment: Please show what you have tried, explaining why the output is insufficient. Also, Could you define extracts: Returning the string without, or only returning the "hardrocks".

Comment: Try a negative look-ahead: `(hardrock)(?!-)` -> https://regex101.com/r/v9wVYw/1

Comment: Which host language (or dialect of regex) are you using?  The answers vary.

Answer (score 2):

This may work, but each match also includes the character following which you may not want.

```
(hardrock)([^-]|$)

Full match: hardrock,
Group 1: hardrock
Group 2: ,

Full match: hardrock,
Group 1: hardrock
Group 2: ,

Full match: hardrock
Group 1: hardrock
Group 2:
```

Comment: Yes, it is great. Thanks Michael!

Answer (score 2):

The search word could be at the beginning `^`, at the end `$`, or surrounded by `,`

This is how it is done using lookarounds to exclude the delimiter from the result:

```
(?<=^|,)hardrock(?=,|$)
```

[<sub>regex101</sub>](https://regex101.com/r/wCMwmd/1)

Answer (score 1):

If the input is separated by `,`, then you'll have to match like this:
(Start of input or `,`) hardrock (End of input or `,`)

You can try `(^|,)(hardrock)($|,)`
If you don't want to capture the `,`, use`(?:^|,)(hardrock)(?:$|,)`

Answer (score 0):

Here, we might want to extract the `hardrock` not followed by a dash. There are several expressions that would do so, such as this one:

```
(hardrock)[^-]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r3Gq7a/1)

Or we can collect all chars in the first capturing group, then get the desired `hardrock` in the second:

```
([\s\S]*?)((hardrock)[^-]|hardrock$)?
```

[image]

```js
const regex = /([\s\S]*?)((hardrock)[^-]|hardrock$)?/gm;
const str = `matt,hardrock,victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock,hardrock,victor,alpha,matt,hardrock-victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock,matt,hardrock,victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock,hardrock,victor,alpha,matt,hardrock-victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Xbs1cp/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqppfS/1)

If comma is undesired, we can use another capturing group:

```
([\s\S]*?)(hardrock)([^-]|$)
```

[image]

```js
const regex = /([\s\S]*?)(hardrock)([^-]|$)/gm;
const str = `hardrock,victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock,hardrock,victor,alpha,matt,hardrock-victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock,matt,hardrock,victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock,hardrock,victor,alpha,matt,hardrock-victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock`;
const subst = `$2\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O1Yjpx/1/)

Comment: Thanks Emma, but this is not capturing the last term hardrock in the given sentence:

 hardrock,victor,alpha,matt,hardrock-victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,**hardrock**

Comment: When I use your second option, it won't capture the first term hardrock in the given sentence: **hardrock**,victor,alpha,matt,hardrock-victor,ben,hardrock,rocker,ranzian,hardrock